# Calculate time difference between 4:00 PM - 1:00 AM (cross midnight)

Tags: android

I'm trying to calculate time difference between 4:00 PM - 1:00 AM but having issues.

**Here is my code**

```java
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        String ends = simpleDateFormat.format(c.getTime());
        Date date1 = null;
        Date date2 = null;

        try {
            date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(4:00 PM);
            date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(1:00 AM);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
        int days = (int) (difference / (1000*60*60*12));
        int hours = (int) ((difference - (1000*60*60*12*days)) / (1000*60*60));
        int min = (int) (difference - (1000*60*60*12*days) - (1000*60*60*hours)) / (1000*60);
        hours = (hours < 0 ? -hours : hours);
        Log.i("======= Hours"," :: "+hours);
```

Comment: date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("4:00 PM"); "4:00 PM" this a string

Comment: "having issues" is a bit unclear, what sort of issues? This also isn't remotely valid Java; for instance, `simpleDateFormat.parse(4:00 PM);` is not at all syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
timeInMs = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()
hour = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeInMs)
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful